# Double Counting(combinatorial proof) for $1^2\binom{n}{1} + 2^2\binom{n}{2}+3^2\binom{n}{3}+...+n^2\binom{n}{n}$ = $n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinations, combinatorial-proofs

can anyone help me with double-counting proof for this equation:
$1^2\binom{n}{1} + 2^2\binom{n}{2}+3^2\binom{n}{3}+...+n^2\binom{n}{n}$ = $n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

I tried this example: we have n+1 bits and at least two "1" bits. it gives just the right side. and also looking at right side in $\binom{n+1}{2}2^{n-1}$ may help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the example you made?

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: @TobyMak we have a binary string with length n+1 and at least  2 one bit. so first should choose 2 places in n+1 places that is n(n+1)/2 and then n+1 -2 = n-1 remaining places can either be one bit or zero bit. so $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sides count the combinations of subsets of $[n]$ with ordered pairs of elements of that subset. On the left, we first choose one of $\binom nk$ subsets with $k$ elements and then choose one of the $k^2$ ordered pairs of its elements. On the right, we first choose an ordered pair of elements and then a subset containing the elements: For the $n(n-1)$ pairs of different elements there are $2^{n-2}$ subsets containing them, and for the $n$ pairs of identical elements there are $2^{n-1}$ subsets containing them, for a total of $n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I only know how to prove it analytically. Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{k}.$
Differentiating, we have 
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k-1}{n \choose k}.
$$
Multiply both sides by $x$ and differentiate them again, then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx}\{xf'(x)\} & = & \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}{n \choose k}\\
f'(x)+xf''(x) & = & \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}x^{k-1}{n \choose k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Put $x=1$, then we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}{n \choose k}\\
 & = & f'(1)+f''(1)\\
 & = & n\cdot2^{n-1}+n(n-1)2^{n-2}\\
 & = & 2^{n-2}n(n+1),
\end{eqnarray*}
provided that $n\geq2$.